# lodash: Identify if the json has certain fields more than 1 item or not

Tags: lodash

I have the json in the below format. I am trying to loop through each object of the json and check for subject and sport parameters. I have to return true if none of the objects doesn't have more than one subject or one sport. If atleast one one object has atleast one property(subject or sport) more than 1 item, then I have to return false

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "peter",
    "subject": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "maths"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "social"
      }
    ],
    "sport": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "football"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "david",
    "subject": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "physics"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "science"
      }
    ],
    "sport": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "soccer"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Justin",
    "subject": [
    ],
,
    "sport": [
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried in the below way, but this returns true even if one object doesn't have any subject or sport

```
if(find(this.gridData, function(o) { return o.subject.length <= 1; }) && 
   find(this.gridData, function(o) { return o.sport.length <= 1; })  
  ){
    return true;
}
else{
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.every()` or lodash's `_.every()` to check if the length of the properties fits the criteria. When the predicate returns `false`, the `every` loop would end, and return `false`.

```js
const arr = [{"id":"1","name":"peter","subject":[{"id":"1","name":"maths"},{"id":"2","name":"social"}],"sport":[{"id":"1","name":"football"}]},{"id":"2","name":"david","subject":[{"id":"2","name":"physics"},{"id":"3","name":"science"}],"sport":[{"id":"2","name":"soccer"}]},{"id":"3","name":"Justin","subject":[],"sport":[]}]

const result = arr.every(({ subject, sport }) =>
  subject.length <= 1 && sport.length <= 1
)

console.log(result)
```